# How to lock screen with SandBox Entitlement under MacOs

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, app-store-connect, sandbox

I use this part of Objective-c source code to lock the screen under MacOs Sierra.

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/Applications/Utilities/Keychain Access.app/Contents/Resources/Keychain.menu"];
Class principalClass = [bundle principalClass];
id instance = [[principalClass alloc] init];
[instance performSelector:@selector(_lockScreenMenuHit:) withObject:nil];
```

It works perfectly, but if I turn on the "App Sandbox" option from capabilities of Project Target, it fails and this error appears on the Xcode console:

```
_SendMessageWithReply:215: ERROR: Attempt to call "SACLockScreenImmediate" from Session 100007
```

I think I must add a temporary exception into the entitlements file, but what are the instructions?